# TypeError when user cancels input dialog

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, input, turtle-graphics

I created a program where the user can any one of the keys "H, "E", "L", "O", "W", "R", "D", and the turtle will draw the corresponding letter in the turtle graphics window. The user is first asked whether or not they want to change the letter dimensions from there default values, and then, depending on their answer, they will either be asked for new letter heights/widths, or be asked to enter a color name. Then, while the program is running, the user can also press any key from F1 - F10 to change the letter color, any number from 1-0 (0 = 10) to change the thickness of each letter, and even change the letter dimensions from what they set in the beginning from a dialog box that comes up when they press "k". And, the user inputting a value in the dialog box is **exactly** where I am having an issue! But first, here is the code for my program:

```
""" A simple typing program

Press "H" to draw an H
Press "E" to draw an E
Press "L" to draw a L
Press "O" to draw an O
Press "W" to draw a W
Press "R" to draw a R
Press "D" to draw a D
Press "ENTER" to go to the next line
Press "TAB" to make an indent
Press "BACKSPACE" to go backwards an indent
Press the "Up" or "Down" arrow keys to move the turtle up or down the canvas
Press "SPACE" to clear the canvas of your drawings
Press "ESC" to exit the program
Press any number from 1-0 on the key board (1 = 1, 0 = 10) to set the letter thickness
Press any key from F1-F10 to set a random color of the letter
(F1-F8 = colors, F9 = Custom Color, F10 = Original color)

That is all you need to know! Enjoy! """

from turtle import *
from tkinter import *
import math
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
import copy

# Function variables

space_width = 30 # Default value: 30
letter_height = 100 # Default value: 100
letter_width = 50 # Default value: 50



change = (input("Would you like to change the size of the letters from the defult value? y/any other input: "))

y = ("yes")
n = ("no")


if change in y:
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                letter_height = int(input("Enter a value from 1-170 to set the height of each letter in pixels: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while letter_height > 170:
            try:
                letter_height = int(input("That value is too much. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
                while letter_height < 1:
                    letter_height = int(input("That value is too little. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while letter_height < 1:
            try:
                letter_height = int(input("That value is too little. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
                while letter_height > 170:
                    letter_height = int(input("That value is too much. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while True:
            try:
                letter_width = int(input("Enter a value from 1-170 to set the width of each letter in pixels: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while letter_width > 170:
            try:
                letter_width = int(input("That value is too much. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
                while letter_width < 1:
                    letter_width = int(input("That value is too little. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while letter_width < 1:
            try:
                letter_width = int(input("That value is too little. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
                while letter_width > 170:
                    letter_width = int(input("That value is too much. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
            break
    except:
        input("That is not an answer! Please enter either y or n!: ")

elif change in n:
    space_width = 30 # Default value: 30
    letter_height = 100 # Default value: 100
    letter_width = 50 # Default value: 50

#The 'while' loop below will tell the user to choose a color name, but if the color is invalid, an exception is thrown, and the user must reenter a color name until a valid color name is entered. 

while True:
    try:
        pen_color=input("Enter a color name to set the pen color: ")
        pencolor(pen_color)
        break
    except:
        print("That is either not an available color or not a valid color name. Please reenter the name of another color or a valid one.")

def NewLetterDimensions():
    global letter_height
    letter_height = (numinput("New Letter Height", "Please set the new letter height: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))

    global letter_width
    letter_width = (numinput("New Letter Width", "Please set the new letter width: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))

    penup()
    goto(xcor(), ycor() +letter_height)
    pendown()
    listen()

def draw_space():
    # Add a space 30 pixels wide.
    penup()
    forward(space_width)
    pendown()

def move_turtle():
    # Pick up the turtle and move it to its starting location.
    penup()
    goto(-200, 100)
    pendown()

def draw_H():
    # Draw the left leg of H.
    # The turtle starts at the bottom left of the letter, pointing right.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    # Draw the bar of the H.
    # The turtle starts at the top of the left leg, pointing up.
    forward(-letter_height/2)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    # Draw the right leg of the H.
    # The turtle starts at the right side of the bar, pointing right.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    forward(-letter_height)
    right(90)
    # The H is drawn.
    # The turtle is in the top right, pointing right.
    draw_space()


def draw_E():
    # Draw an E.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    forward(-letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    forward(-letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_L():
    # Draw an L
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    forward(-letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_O():
    # Draw an O
    forward(letter_width)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_newline():
    # This funtion will pick up the turtle and move it to a second line below HELLO
    penup()
    goto(xcor(), ycor() -letter_height-5)
    pendown()

def draw_W():
    # This function will draw a W
    left(105)
    forward(letter_height)
    backward(letter_height)
    right(40)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    right(131)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(141)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(165)
    penup()
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    draw_space()

def draw_second_O():
    # This function will draw the O in "world"
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    penup()
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    draw_space()

def draw_R(letter_width, letter_height):
    # This function will draw an R

    slant_height = (math.sqrt(letter_width**2 + (letter_height/2)**2))
    slant_angle = (90+(90-(math.degrees(math.acos(letter_width/slant_height)))))
    space_angle = (180 - slant_angle)

    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    left(slant_angle)
    forward(slant_height)
    left(space_angle)
    draw_space()

def draw_D(letter_width, letter_height):
    # This function will draw a REAL D

    angle_height = math.sqrt(letter_width**2 + (letter_height/2)**2)
    D_angle = (90+(math.degrees(math.acos(letter_width/angle_height))))
    Second_D_angle = ((90 - (D_angle-90)) + (90-(math.degrees(math.acos(letter_width/angle_height)))))
    D_space_angle = (math.degrees(math.atan(letter_width/(letter_height/2))))

    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(D_angle)
    forward(angle_height)
    right(Second_D_angle)
    forward(angle_height)
    left(90+D_space_angle)
    penup()
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def skip(x, y):
    penup()
    goto(x, y)
    pendown()

def back():
    penup()
    bk(letter_width + space_width)
    pendown()

def walk():
    penup()
    forward(letter_width + space_width)
    pendown()

def soar():
    penup()
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height + 5)
    right(90)
    pendown()

def fall():
    penup()
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height + 5)
    left(90)
    pendown()

setup(1.0, 1.0)

def RotateRight():
    right(90)

def RotateLeft():
    left(90)

def Up():
    penup()
    goto(xcor(),ycor()+(letter_height+5))
    pendown()

def width1():
    width(1)

def width2():
    width(2)

def width3():
    width(3)

def width4():
    width(4)

def width5():
    width(5)

def width6():
    width(6)

def width7():
    width(7)

def width8():
    width(8)

def width9():
    width(9)

def width10():
    width(10)

def Blue():
    color("blue")

def Red():
    color("red")

def DarkGreen():
    color("dark green")

def Purple():
    color("purple")

def Pink():
    color("pink")

def Brown():
    color("brown")

def Orange():
    color("orange")

def Black():
    color("Black")

def OriginalColor():
    color(pen_color)

def getColor():
    Color = askcolor()
    color_name = Color[1]
    colormode(255)
    color(color_name)

move_turtle()
speed(0)
color(pen_color)
listen()
##onkey(Color, "F10")
onkey(NewLetterDimensions, "k")
onkey(width1, "1")
onkey(width2, "2")
onkey(width3, "3")
onkey(width4, "4")
onkey(width5, "5")
onkey(width6, "6")
onkey(width7, "7")
onkey(width8, "8")
onkey(width9, "9")
onkey(width10, "0")
onkey(Blue, "F1")
onkey(Red, "F2")
onkey(DarkGreen, "F3")
onkey(Purple, "F4")
onkey(Pink, "F5")
onkey(Brown, "F6")
onkey(Orange, "F7")
onkey(Black, "F8")
onkey(getColor, "F9")
onkey(OriginalColor, "F10")
onscreenclick(goto)
onscreenclick(skip)
onkey(clear, "space")
onkey(back, "BackSpace")
onkey(walk, "Tab")
onkey(Up, "Up")
onkey(draw_H, "h")
onkey(bye, "Escape")
onkey(draw_E, "e")
onkey(draw_L, "l")
onkey(draw_O, "o")
onkey(draw_W, "w")
onkey(lambda: draw_R(letter_width, letter_height), "r")
onkey(lambda: draw_D(letter_width, letter_height), "d")
onkey(draw_newline, "Return")
```

Here is where I am having the issue:

```
def NewLetterDimensions():
    global letter_height
    letter_height = (numinput("New Letter Height", "Please set the new letter height: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))

    global letter_width
    letter_width = (numinput("New Letter Width", "Please set the new letter width: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))

    penup()
    goto(xcor(), ycor() +letter_height)
    pendown()
    listen()
```

The issue is that, when the dialog box comes up, and the user selects "cancel" instead of entering a value, I get this error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py", line 119, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/queue.py", line 172, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 686, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "/Users/Rohan/Google Drive/K12 High School Documents/Computer_Science/section_5/assignment_5a.py", line 111, in NewLetterDimensions
    goto(xcor(), ycor() +letter_height)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType
```

The user pressing enter of course returns nothing, but apparently, this cannot be used in operations for some reason. Well, how can I make it so that, if the user cancels the dialog, the program can just continue on from the previous heights/widths set, so that the error does not come up? Any help regarding this issue is VERY much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the error is on the line 117, in the `NewLetterDimensions()` function, as you try to add a `NoneType` to a `float`.

You could check whether `letter_height` is None; if yes then return the same dimensions otherwise update them.

Also, instead of defining functions `width1()` to `width12()`, the original `width` function already accept a parameter `size`, so you can bind the buttons like this:

```
for number in range(0, 11):
    onkey(width(number), str(number % 10))
```

Comment: I tried "if" statements like this: `if letter_height == None:
        return letter_height
    else:
        letter_height` and this `if letter_width == None:
        return letter_width
    else:
        letter_width` and now, whenever I type "k" and press cancel, the error does not come up anymore, but when I try to type any key that draws a letter, nothing happens!

Comment: @R.Kap: I assume that is because you use `penup()`, when `letter_height is None` put a `pendown()` into the block.

Comment: Actually, I just fixed it myself by taking out the `else` statements and then putting `listen()` at the end of the "if" statements! However, I am also trying to return the values that the user had before, but I cannot find a way to do that. `return` apparently just stops it from executing, so, how else could I make the "if" statement return the height's and width's old values?

Comment: You could save them at the beginning of the function and if you encounter the `None` case then restore the old values instead of doing nothing. :)

Comment: I try that, but I just get this error: `SyntaxWarning: name 'letter_height' is used prior to global declaration`. How else can I save it other than just assign the old value to a new variable? Because, that is just what I did.

Comment: I even tried saving it as a definition before the `NewLetterDimensions` function definition, and I still get the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Any other way to do this?